# How to put code chunks in details, summary?

Tags: markdown

I want to put code chunks 'inside' the 'details' section.

Just like the one [link](https://gist.github.com/ericclemmons/b146fe5da72ca1f706b2ef72a20ac39d). If you click 'Click to expand!' there comes a code.

At first I just did as usual,

````
<details>
<summary>BlahBlah</summary>
blahblah2

Tried to put code chunks here starts with '```'

blahblah3
</details>
````

And it fails. Code chunks are not inside the 'details' section.

Parts starting from code chunks to 'blahblah3' all pop up.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I found out that this problem is called "collapsible markdown".

So you can search some useful answers using that keyword.

One of the most useful answer was [here](https://www.endtoend.ai/blog/collapsible-code-blocks/), but the method 1 didn't really work for me.

I used method 2 which used adding kramdown to markdown.

But still, I managed to put code block in the 'details', but the results of the code block really didn't include in the 'details'.

It seems like it doesn't work, because I didn't see any examples yet.

Comment: Sadly this link is dead :|

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid Looks like info still can be found via the keyword "collapsible markdown", for example, https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab

Comment: Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Kramdown:

````
{::options parse_block_html="true" /}

<details><summary markdown="span">code</summary>
```python
print('Hello World!')
```
</details>

{::options parse_block_html="false" /}
````

[Source](https://www.endtoend.ai/tutorial/collapsible-code-blocks/)